# Question related to symmetry in distances

Tags: distance, euclidean, symmetry

My dataset represents products and evaluation of every product by users. E.g., I might have:

```
{
    {'Customer':'John Doe', "likes":['Apple':'1', 'Orange':'3']},
    {'Customer':'Jane Doe', "likes":['Apple':'5', 'Orange':'3']}
}
```

Our solution implements a simple Euclidian distance to determine how similar tastes two users have. However, this  similarity is calculated based on a given vector against which we need to calculate. Suppose we want to find people that like apples. The given vector might look as following

```
{'Customer':'Apple liker', 'likes':['Apple':3]}
```

The distance for both John Doe and Jane Doe will be 2. Is there a way to differentiate the fact that even though they have the same distance, Jane really likes apples?

Answer (score 2):

First, the differences in your example will not both be 2; one will be -2 and the other +2 because John prefers oranges while Jane prefers apples.

But suppose the values were 1, 3 and 3, 5.  Then the distances would be equal if you used simple distances.  But that's easy to change.  The simplest method would be to square the values.  Then 1, 3 would change to 1, 9 while 3, 5 would change to 9, 25 and that would capture "really liking" apples.  That might be too extreme; you could use the 1.5 power if you prefer.